# How to make a require object available whenever I type something in search bar in django?

Tags: python, html, django

I made a search bar but whenever I write something in it, the link shows `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?srh=something` and I am not understanding why the the specific `picture with title` is not showing. It is showing me all pics with title but I want only that pic with title which I write as a title in search bar. Which things to add in this code?

*index.html*

```
{% load static %}
{% static 'images/fulls' as baseUrl %}
{% static 'images/thumbs' as hiUrl %}  

    <form class="new" method="GET" action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder='Search..' name="srh" value="{{request.GET.srh}}"> <br>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"> Search </button>
    </form>

   <div>
    {% for dest1 in target1 %}
    {% if dest1 %}
     <div>
      <a href="{{baseUrl}}/{{dest1.img}}">
       <img src="{{hiUrl}}/{{dest1.img}}" alt="" />
       <h3>{{dest1.title}}</h3>
     </a>
   </div>
   {% endif %}
   {%endfor%}
  </div>
```

*views.py*

```
def index(request):
    query = request.GET.get('srh')
    if query:
        match = Destination.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)

        target1 = a, b= [Destination() for __ in range(2)]
        a.img = 'Article.jpg'
        b.img = 'Micro Tasks.jpeg'

        a.title = 'Article Writing'
        b.title = 'Micro Tasks'

        context = {
        'target1': target1,
       }
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
    else:
       return render(request, 'index.html')
```

*models.py*

```
class Destination(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Will somebody answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't understand why you use a and b but i think this will solve the problem

```
def index(request):
    query = request.GET.get('srh')

    if query:
        match = Destination.objects.get(desc=query)
        context = {
            'match': match,
        }

        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

```
<div>
    { % if match %}
     <div>
      <a href="{{baseUrl}}/{{match.img}}">
       <img src="{{hiUrl}}/{{match.img}}" alt="" />
       <h3>{{match.title}}</h3>
     </a>
   </div>
   {% endif %}
  </div>
```

Comment: I updated the code. You can see it above but whenever I type any title in it, it is showing me all the titles although I want only that particular title with image.

Comment: do not use icontains, it returns all title that contains your query.  and you did not add match query on context, why?

Comment: Okay I used ```title=query``` but it is not returning particular result. Instead it is giving me all the titles. I used ```target1``` instead of match. Please check the code.

Comment: ```Destination.objects.get(desc=query)```. It is giving me operational error.

Comment: I am not understanding what are you asking?

Comment: can i see your models?